# How to install hickle on Anaconda?

Tags: package, installation, anaconda

I am trying to install hickle on Anaconda. I am kind of new in Anaconda, so I google it and I found the simple:

```
$ conda install -c clyde_fare hickle
```

which was taken from "https://anaconda.org/clyde_fare/hickle"
Any ideas ? Thanks in advance

```
$ conda install -c clyde_fare hickle
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - hickle

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/clyde_fare/linux-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/clyde_fare/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
```

looking for, navigate to

```
    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: You could try this `conda install -c conda-forge <package>`

Comment: I´ve tried:Sorry,
    $ conda install -c conda_forge hickle
Got the same error message :(

Answer (score 1):

the simple:

```
$pip install hickle
```

worked just fine. It´s important that I have a local (/home/myuser) anaconda instalation with a patched path (so, when I run python as myuser, the anaconda´s python will run).